# create a Scale9Sprite in quick-cocos

Tags: lua, cocos2d-x

Bt using function following may create a Scale9Sprite

display.newScale9Sprite(filename, x, y, size, capInsets)

The image is packed in a pvr.ccz file which is encrypted. I don't think using the function above is a good way to do the job.

So I wonder whether there is a function may create Scale9Sprite from SpriteFrame? Or I have to save the image in a single file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`CCScale9Sprite:createWithSpriteFrame(spriteFrame, capInsets)`

and

`CCScale9Sprite:createWithSpriteFrameName(spriteFrameName, capInsets)`

to create your sprite.